# Testing GraphQL API

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, graphql, chai-http

I'm testing my GraphQL API, but I would like to clean it up a little bit. It's worth noting I'm using `chai-http` for the network requests. Here's what I'm currently doing (which works):

```
let createUser = (()=> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chai.request(server)
      .post('/api/graphql/')
      .set('content-type', 'application/json')
      .send({ 'query' : 
        'mutation users { \
          user : addUser(inputs: { \
            firstName: \"Test\", \
            lastName: \"User\", \
            email: \"test@test.com\", \
          }) { \
            id, \
            firstName \
          } \
        }'
      })
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) { reject(err) }
        let data = res.body.data;
        let user = data.user;
        resolve(user);
      })
  });
});
```

However, I would like to clean it up a bit and do something like this:

```
let createUser = (() => {
  let newUser = {
    firstName: 'Test',
    lastName: 'User',
    email: 'test@test.com'
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chai.request(server)
      .post('/api/graphql/')
      .set('content-type', 'application/json')
      .send({ 'query' : 
        'mutation users { \
          user : addUser(inputs: ' + JSON.stringify(newUser) + ') { \
            id, \
            firstName \
          } \
        }'
      })
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) { reject(err) }
        let data = res.body.data;
        let user = data.user;
        resolve(user);
      })
  });
});
```

However, this style does of placing the object inputs does not work and returns a bad request error. Here is what part of the returned error object reads:

[image]

Any ideas why this doesn't work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like there's an issue with your JSON input there. It could be some combination of your line breaks and your quotes that's not getting parse properly on the server.

However, I still wouldn't recommend in-lining your variables like that in your GraphQL query. You should do something like this instead:

```
let createUser = (() => {
  let newUser = {
    firstName: 'Test',
    lastName: 'User',
    email: 'test@test.com'
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chai.request(server)
      .post('/api/graphql/')
      .set('content-type', 'application/json')
      .send({
        'query' : 'mutation users ($input: CreateUserInput!) { \
          user : addUser(inputs: $input) { \
            id, \
            firstName \
          } \
        }',
        'variables' : {
           'input': newUser
         }
      })
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) { reject(err) }
        let data = res.body.data;
        let user = data.user;
        resolve(user);
      })
  });
});
```

You can check out another [simple example here](https://docs.scaphold.io/coredata/mutations/#create) as to how you can execute a mutation on Scaphold to create a user with `query` and `variables` split out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks bud, will try it out! @vince

Comment: Hey @vince, anyway to clean up the response I want back? Say I wanted id, firstName, lastName, facebookUID, email, etc.. returned after creation? What do you think?

Comment: In that case you could always just return more fields. Right now, the query is returning `id` and `firstName`, but you can also keep adding to that list and include `lastName`, `facebookUID`, `email`, etc.